# Getting false warning on 'unknown props' in react

Tags: reactjs

I've following code,
I've created a dumb component,

```
const editViewTable = ({ headerData, bodyData }) =>
(
  <div>.....</div>
)

editViewTable.propTypes = {
  headerData: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string),
  bodyData: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
};

export default editViewTable;
```

And an intelligent one,

```
import * as actions from './actions';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getOnehopProducts } from './reducers';
import editViewTable from '../common/editViewTable/component';

const mapStateToProps = (state, params) => {
  return {
    headerData: ['name', 'category', 'merchant'],
    bodyData: getOnehopProducts(state)
  };
}

class ProductList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

    fetchData() {
        const { fetchProducts } = this.props;
        fetchProducts({});
    }

  render(){
    const { headerData, bodyData } = this.props;
    return <editViewTable headerData={headerData} bodyData={bodyData} />;
  }
}


ProductList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(ProductList);

export default ProductList;
```

Whenever I'm rendering the component, I'm getting the error `Warning: Unknown props 'headerData', 'bodyData' on <editViewTable> tag. Remove these props from the element`.

I'm unable to find, what's causing the problem. I'm clearly not passing extra props, so what's causing the error. I'm pretty much newbie to react.

I'm using react-material.

Answer (score 1):

After renaming `editViewTable` to `EditViewTable`, this warning has gone, and everything is working fine and dandy.